# How to print parameters in a JSON format?

Tags: python, json

I want to create a function that takes the parameters and makes a json object with them. 
I have this code for Example.

```
   def sendOrder(symbol, orderType, volume, openPrice, slippage = 0, stopLoss = 0, takeProfit = 0, comment = 0,
    magic = 0, expiration = 0) :
    sendOrderJson = json.dumps(locals())
    print(sendOrderJson)
```

And when I call this:

```
sendOrder(symbol='EURUSD', orderType='buy', volume=0.5, openPrice=1.1050)
```

I get this:

```
{"symbol": "EURUSD", "orderType": "buy", "volume": 0.5, "openPrice": 1.105, "slippage": 0, "stopLoss": 0, "takeProfit": 0, "comment": 0, "magic": 0, "expiration": 0}
```

Instead, I want to get this:

```
{"messageType" : "sendOrder", "symbol": "EURUSD", "orderType": "buy", "volume": 0.5, "openPrice": 1.105, "slippage": 0, "stopLoss": 0, "takeProfit": 0, "comment": 0, "magic": 0, "expiration": 0}
```

So I want to add `"messageType"` in the JSON object, but I don't want to include that in the parameter since it's going to be hardcoded. How can I do that? Is there a simple way to do it while still using `locals()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The locals function returns a dict. Simply add the additional key before dumping it to JSON.

```py
   def sendOrder(symbol, orderType, volume, openPrice, slippage = 0, stopLoss = 0, takeProfit = 0, comment = 0,
    magic = 0, expiration = 0) :
    dic = locals()
    dic["messageType"] = "sendOrder"
    sendOrderJson = json.dumps(dic)
    print(sendOrderJson)
```

We can do this also a bit more fancy, using unpacking (also known as splat or spread).

```py
sendOrderJson = json.dumps({"messageType": "sendOrder", **locals()})
```

Comment: Thank you sir, the second option works better since it adds 'messageType' first. Can you tell me what are the ** before locals()

Comment: It should be also noted, that locals() must be called as first thing inside function in this case. Any attribute definitions before it will pass into it.

Answer (score 1):

A few simple options that come to mind, not sure if you had requirements you left out, but when you say "json format" it seems you are just describing python dictionaries.

---

dict

```
>>> dict(symbol='EURUSD', orderType='buy', volume=0.5, openPrice=1.1050)
{'volume': 0.5, 'orderType': 'buy', 'symbol': 'EURUSD', 'openPrice': 1.105}
```

---

kwargs

```
def foo(**kwargs):
   kwargs['messageType'] = 'sendOrder'
   return kwargs

>>> foo(symbol='EURUSD', orderType='buy', volume=0.5, openPrice=1.1050)
{'volume': 0.5, 'orderType': 'buy', 'symbol': 'EURUSD', 'messageType': 'sendOrder', 'openPrice': 1.105}
```

---

A dataclass (python 3) would allow defaults and easy translation between tuple/dict/etc.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict

@dataclass
class Stuff:
    messageType: str = "sendOrder"
    symbol: str = "EURUSD"
    # Add your other fields

>>> Stuff()
Stuff(messageType='sendOrder', symbol='EURUSD')

>>> Stuff(symbol='abc')
Stuff(messageType='sendOrder', symbol='abc')

>>> asdict(Stuff(symbol='abc'))
{'messageType': 'sendOrder', 'symbol': 'abc'}
```